# c# 2 models in same view

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to take 2 views in same page. In my HomeController i get back informations of my database. But i have problems when i want to show informations in my view.

Homecontroler

```
 public ActionResult DetailEquipe()
    {
        List<EquipePersonnel> Viewep = new List<EquipePersonnel>();

        string path = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        //string id = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/"));
        string id = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        ViewBag.ID = id;

        ViewBag.test = "testfail";
        List<Equipe> equipe = new List<Equipe>();
        List<Personnel> personnel = new List<Personnel>();
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new QC.SqlConnection(
         "Server = connection...."
         ))
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully.");
                using (var command = new QC.SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandType = DT.CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = @"Select * from Equipe where Id='" + id + "'";
                    EquipePersonnel ep = new EquipePersonnel();
                    QC.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Equipe c = new Equipe();
                        c.equipe_id = reader["equipe_id"] as String;
                        c.Id = reader["Id"] as String;
                        c.equipe_nom_equipe = reader["equipe_nom_equipe"] as String;
                        equipe.Add(c);

                    }




                    command.CommandText = @"Select * from Personnel where Pers_ID_equipe='" + id + "'";

                    QC.SqlDataReader reader2 = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader2.Read())
                    {
                        Personnel p = new Personnel();
                        p.Pers_Nom = reader2["Pers_Nom"] as String;
                        p.Pers_Prenom= reader2["Pers_Prenom"] as String;
                        p.Id= reader2["Id"] as String;
                        p.Pers_statut = reader2["Pers_statut"] as bool? ?? false;
                        personnel.Add(p);

                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
                    return View(Viewep);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "problème connection";
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            return View(ex);
        }
    }
```

It's my view where i want to see Equipe and Personnel item

```html
@model IList<RapportDeChantier.Models.EquipePersonnel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DétailEquipe";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <center> <h3>@ViewBag.test</h3>
        <table id="tableau">
           @foreach (var item in Model.Equipe)
            {
          <tr><td>Equipe</td><td>item.equipe_nom_equipe</td></tr>
            }
        </table></center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Your question is not very clear but maybe you mean you want 2 models in 1 view. In that case create a new model that has your other 2 models as properties and pass that. 2. Your controller code is very convoluted and there are calls that are not best practice like not wrapping your sql calls with `using` blocks or even having sql calls directly in your controller which is not very good SoS. Please read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: Which is commonly known as a Viewmodel. Plus: Paramterize your queries. Think of little bobby tables!

Answer (score 6):

Create a view model (ie. HomeViewModel):

```
public class HomeViewModel 
{
    public List<Equipe> Equipe { get; set;}
    public List<Personnel> Personnel { get; set;}
}
```

Fill in `Equipe` and `Personnel` when you read data from your database:

```
var viewModel = new HomeViewModel();
viewModel.Equipe = //Equipe data
viewModel.Personnel = //Personnel data
return View(viewModel);
```

then return this model to your view instead.

```
@model RapportDeChantier.Models.EquipePersonnel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DétailEquipe";
}
...
<div>
    <center>
        <h3>@ViewBag.test</h3>
        <table id="tableau_equippe">
           @foreach (var item in Model.Equipe)
            {
              <tr><td>Equipe</td><td>item.equipe_nom_equipe</td></tr>
            }
        </table>
   </center>
</div>

<div>
    <center>
        <h3>@ViewBag.test</h3>
        <table id="tableau_personnel">
           @foreach (var person in Model.Personnel)
            {
              <tr><td>Person</td><td>item.PersonNom</td></tr>
            }
        </table>
   </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tuple<Model1,Model2>` like in this example

Models

```
public class Model1
{
  public string Test {get; set;}
}
public class Model2
{
  public string Test2 {get; set;}
}
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult DetailEquipe()
 {
    Tuple<Model1, Model2> tuple = new Tuple<Model1, Model2>(new Model1(), new Model2());
    return View(tuple);
 }
```

.cshtml

```
@model Tuple<Model1,Model2>
<input asp-for="Item1.Test"/>   
<input asp-for="Item2.Test2"/>
```